# Grails - How to covert a query result (from MongoDB) to a JSON string without redundant fields

Tags: json, mongodb, grails, grails-domain-class, database

I have the following domain class

```
class Settings {
    static constraints = {
        pageID(nullable: false, unique: true)
        lp()
    }

    String pageID
    Map lp
}
```

I'm querying the DB like SO:

```
...
def query = Settings.where {pageID == id}
def result = query.find()
```

Here is a screen shot of the evaluated result:
[image]

Now I'm looking for a way to format the result as a JSON like so:

```
{"lp":{"account":"12345678","appKey":"64dsfg64dg64fg65dfg6","domain":"my.domain.com"},"pageID":"123456"}
```

What is the right way to extract the fields out? It would be best if I can avoid getting each field manually. Thanks :)

Comment: If your result is a `DBObject`, you can obtain a JSON string just by calling `toString()` on it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, my result is from type Settings (my domain class) ... any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I did not find a native function, I used @Jinzhao Wu approach and wrote this helper function:

```
def getDBRecord(Object dc) {
    def jo = new JSONObject()
    def domainClass = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(dc.class)
    def props = domainClass.getPersistantProperties()
    for (int i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        jo.put(props[i].name, dc[props[i].name]);
    }
    return jo;
}
```

Hope that help others

Answer (score 0):

Just use gorm dynamic finder:

```
def result = Settings.findByPageId(id)
render result as JSON
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, however I still get fields that are not a part of my domain class (like :errors, metaClass etc') so if I render it as JSON my client gets extra redundant fields

Comment: Use remove method like result.remove('errors') to get rid of useless fields. Or render result.persistentProperties

Comment: That's what I do right now, I feel it is the wrong way. As I see it there must be a more elegant way to get just the fields you defined in the domain class.

Comment: The way you put in your answer is not what I recommended.